# What is a 'trusted root certificate' and where do I get it to sign a Windows 8.1 App?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, certificate, windows-8.1

I'm creating a Line-Of-Business application for Windows 8.1+

I've completed the Apple variation and haven't had any issues with distribution.

In regards to releasing for Windows I'm told I need to sign my application with a trusted root certificate.

From what I can tell I can get these from Symantic or Digicert (I'm sure there are more options too).

**1) Can someone tell me exactly what this is and why I need it?**

**2) Do I need the standard certificate or the "Extended Validation" certificate?**

**3) How would one sign their application with this certificate after it has been obtained?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes with Windows Desktop app we are going with sing in application with "Symantic of Digicert" certification and etc.

But with Windows Store app here things are different you need to do "Associate app with the Store..".

Here are the steps for it:-

1. Do right click on your project from solution explorer >> Select Store >> then select "Associate app with the Store..".
2. By it it will automatically download all content from store. 
   Notes :- You have to do "Reserve app name on Store" first.

=> You need Developer Dashboard account for Windows Store for it.
Check attached image for 1 and 2 so you can get idea.!

=> It also will download "YourAppName_StoreKey.pfx" file in your project, which you require.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer doesn't seem very clear to me. I don't want to distribute through the Windows Store. I need to do an Enterprise Distribution.